# How to estimate random-effects for new subjects for predictions (example in GNU R's lme4)

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm wondering how to make predictions for new subjects from a fitted mixed-effects model (in a frequentist framework).

Specifically, we have multiple observations on a set of subjects to which we can fit a mixed-effects model with subject-specific random-intercept and random-slope, across a range of time points (say 0-9).

Now, we observe new subjects for a few initial time points (say 0-5). We want to make predictions for these new subjects at time points 6-9, using the fitted model.

So, the steps I envisage are:

1. Estimate a model using the first set of subjects, getting
   the fixed-effects and random-effect covariance.
2. Using the fitted model, get estimates for the new subject
   random-intercept and random-slope on their observed data.
3. Finally, make predictions for new subjects at unobserved times using their subject-specific random-effects.

I'm unsure on how to proceed with step (2). I assume it would be possible to estimate the subject-specific random-effects using Maximum Likelihood (ML), and these estimates would be independent for each new subject - since we don't want any feedback from the new subjects into the inference for the model (step 2 should have no effect on step 1). However, it is typical to fit mixed-effects models in a Restricted Maximum Likelihood (REML) framework, since ML leads to biased estimated of the random-effects covariance... but will that be true for estimating a subject-specific random-effect conditional on the covariance, or is ML sufficient?

For step (3), there is the obvious question of how much uncertainty will be propagated through this process. If we use ML to estimate the new subject-specific random-effects, we will be completely ignoring the uncertainty in the first model. We could bootstrap the whole process to get a distribution on the subject-specific random-effects. Plan B would be to switch to a Bayesian approach, although for now I'm interested in the frequentist version.

To make this concrete, I present the following minimal working example using `lme4` in `GNU R` and the in-built `sleepstudy` dataset

```
R.Version()$version.string
## "R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)"                                                                                                     
library("lme4")
packageVersion("lme4")
## ‘1.1.13’                                                                                                                           
library("merTools")
packageVersion("merTools")
## ‘0.3.0’                                                                                                                            


data("sleepstudy")

summary(sleepstudy)
nlevels(sleepstudy$Subject) ## 18 subjects                                                                                            


## Fit model to "Observed" data (only 15 subjects)                                                                                                       
sleepstudy.reduced <- subset( sleepstudy, Subject %in% levels(sleepstudy$Subject)[1:15] )

FITTED.reduced <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy.reduced)


## Then imagine we get new observations on three new subjects on fewer days                                                                                   
sleepstudy.newdata <- subset( sleepstudy, (Subject %in% levels(sleepstudy$Subject)[16:18]) & (Days<=5) )

## ... and we want to make predictions for these subjects at new Days                                                                 
sleepstudy.toPredict <- subset( sleepstudy, (Subject %in% levels(sleepstudy$Subject)[16:18]), c("Days","Subject") )

## So, given FITTED.reduced,                                                                                                          
## can we estimates random-effects for the new subjects (sleepstudy.newdata)                                                          
##                                                                                                                                    
## Then plug those into predict(?) to get outcomes at new Days (sleepstudy.toPredict)      


## something like
## FITTED.newdata <- ( sleepstudy.newdata | FITTED.reduced )
## ^^^^ this is the bit I can't see how to do ^^^^

## followed by
## PREDICT <- predict( FITTED.newdata, newdata=sleepstudy.toPredict )
```

I've had a play with `predict.merMod()`, `simulate.merMod()` and `predictInterval()` from `merTools`-package, but I can't quite see how to use them to solve this problem.

The next step, as I see it, would be to obtain the likelihood of observing the new subjects conditional on the fitted model.

Comment: No argument if people feel the question is off-topic, can someone (with higher reputation than me) please move it to  stackoverflow - if that is deemed a more appropriate community.

Comment: This is asking a statistical question, not a programming one. I vote to reopen.

Comment: If your question is just, "if `lme4` can estimate the random-effects for new subjects given a fitted model", then it is about `lme4`, not statistics.  But, *how to* 'estimate the random-effects for new subjects given a fitted model' would be a perfectly on-topic & good question here. Which are you really interested in?

Comment: I'd like to know how to solve this problem, I have a bias of how to do it `GNU R` with `lme4` since that is what I am using (partly why I put that bit of the question title in brackets), but any demonstration would be helpful.

Part of the wider question is about whether these random-effects should be estimated as ML or REML, I'd say the latter... but I'm not familiar enough with REML to know whether that is sensible.

I'll add these statistical concerns to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a fitted linear mixed effects model predict longitudinal output for a new subject?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/367521/how-does-a-fitted-linear-mixed-effects-model-predict-longitudinal-output-for-a-n)